# Не проходит авторизация на форуме. В чем причина?

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Main http = new Main();

        System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
        http.sendGet();

        System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
        http.sendPost();

    }

    // HTTP GET request
    private void sendGet() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://sysadmins.ru/login.php";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://sysadmins.ru/login.php";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "username=Megatron666&password=123456&redirect=&login=%C2%F5%EE%E4";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Не вижу ничего похожего на работу с куками.
2. Сервер может делать редирект, куки от которого теряются. В таком случае следует отключать автоматическое исполнение редиректа и доставать куки.
3. `%C2%F5%EE%E4` - win1251 в параметрах - это точно нормально?
4. `"Mozilla/5.0"` - это не тянет на нормальный useragent.

PS: Дополнительная [полезная информация](//bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=43360) по реализации входа (код на VB.NET).